# How to put html table into latex document (not as a figure)

Tags: tables, html

I have an html table like `<table>...</table>` with some css formatting and I'd like to put that table into latex document. I don't want to put it as a figure because I will not ba able to copy its content. How can I do that (preservig formatting and styling)?

Comment: using a figure does not mean you can not copy content, you can print the html table to pdf and then include the pdf and the text will still be text that can be selected, not a bitmap image